# Is there a language that pumps, but is not regular?

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I'm looking for a concrete language that can be pumped but is not regular. I understand that closure properties can be used to further test if a language is regular/nonregular.

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Converse_of_lemma_not_true)

Comment: Has been answered several times on this site.